# Bootstrap inline form not working with simple form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am having trouble to display my simple_form inline:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= simple_form_for '', :html => { :class => 'form-inline' }, url: vehicleTrack_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :search, collection: @all_vehicles, :label_method => :objectno, :label => 'Vehiculo' %>
        <%= f.button :submit, value: "Buscar",:name => nil%>
    <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Displays:

[image]

However if I just try Bootstrap demo code it works fine:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Displays:

[image]

Comment: can you send the screenshot of inspect element in your browser so we can check how the code render in browser.

Comment: did you try setting the elements in the form to display: inline?